# Words to replace demonstrate or perform for dancing team?

Tags: word-choice

> The cultural dance team ***demonstrate/perform/showcase*** some of their nation's traditional dances such as ...

What would be the best word to replace the bold words above?

Comment: Best in what sense?  They all work equally well in my opinion. What was their purpose in doing these dances?

Comment: Camp followers, anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the intended audience, I would probably use **perform**.

*Demonstrate* means to show clearly, which a dance team probably could but it's more often used in the context of proving a point  – although it would not be wrong to use it.

*Showcase*, since it has been used as a verb, means to display, which could be used in the OP sentence, but I believe the best option is to use *perform* (again, depending on the audience) as its meaning is (from https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/perform):
2 
: to entertain an audience by singing, acting, etc.
[no object]
The band will be performing on the main stage.
She's a wonderful singer who loves to perform before a live audience.